# IE7 javascript command line tool

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, developer-tools

I have the IE7 Developer Toolbar for IE7. It doesn't allow you to change styles of elements nor does it have a JS command line feature/console. IE8 Developer Tools has a javascript command line. I need to debug something that is just in IE7 using a JS command line.

Does anyone know of an IE7 extension to run JavaScript during runtime? I have exhausted google looking for something.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that Firebug Lite will do the trick.

http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

Answer (score 0):

The standard IEDevToolbar does let you change styles. Its the interface bewtween the DOM and CSS panes.

For a JS command console Ive been using [DebugBar](http://www.debugbar.com/?langage=en) which im not completely happy with. But it works.

Comment: Ah I see now. The styles show up under the attributes list and you can change them there. Yeah, I had issues getting DebugBar installed and working right.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this myself, but you can use IE8 and switch to IE7 Compatability View

Comment: For this web application I am already in IE7 compat mode for other reasons, although I wish I wasn't :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to IE developer tools and go to console tab. down the bottom there is a box where you can run js like alert('hello world') for example.